# Including external jar in Tomcat ClassPath

Tags: java, tomcat

In Tomcat I want to use a jar inside a web application. The jar file will exist outside of the Tomcat directory.

To include the jar file in tomcat classpath, I modified the TomcatHome/conf/catalina.properties to include the absolute path of my jar file like,

```
shared.loader=D:\jaa\MyJarFile.jar
```

as per the suggestion given in link,

```
http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-classpath
```

But it throws the error,

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

I have also tried ,

```
shared.loader=D:\jaa\*.jar

shared.loader=file:\\D:\jaa\MyJarFile.jar
```

None of them seem to work :(

If I try placing the jar inside tomcat/lib it seem to work. But I am not allowed to do that.

Please help me out with this issue as I have implementation the next week..

Comment: Did you try: `file://path/to/foldername/jarname.jar`?Your syntax is different

Comment: Tomcat raises IllegalArgumentsException when I use forward slash(/) while server startup. So I got to use backslash(file:\\D:\jaa\PatMS.jar)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add JAR libraries to WAR project without facing java.lang.ClassNotFoundException? Classpath vs Build Path vs /WEB-INF/lib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792197/how-to-add-jar-libraries-to-war-project-without-facing-java-lang-classnotfoundex)

Comment: What worked for me was to use quotes and forward slashes, like _shared.folder="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/db/lib/*.jar"_ (on a Windows system).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I figured myself how to add the classpath for tomcat. Instead of editing catalina.properties, just create a "setenv.sh" in the Tomcat Bin directory with the classpath,

Example,

```
CLASSPATH=D:\jaa\MyJarFile.jar
```

I just checked the catalina.sh in Tomcat/bin and these classpath variable will be set while setting the bootstrap as the classpath.

Comment: It's worth noting that the `CLASSPATH` environment variable is explicitly *unset* by `catalina.sh`, so you must use edit `setenv.sh` to set it.

Answer (score 1):

I was using IntelliJ and I tried everything like:

1. Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> (Project Settings) and adding a dependency of `mysql-connector.jar`. Didn't work. (The only thing that worked was that code completion **inside** IntelliJ was working fine.
2. Adding `mysql-connector.jar` to apache-home/lib/ folder. Didn't work.
3. Including `mysql-connector.jar` from Maven inside IntelliJ. Just didn't work.

*The thing that worked for me*:

Include the `mysql-connector.jar` file in the `PROJECT/web/WEB-INF/lib` folder.

No need to add it as a dependency anywhere. Just compile this and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I find myself copying extra JARs, which should be available for all contexts and should therefor go into the root loader, into the following directory:

```
 C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\lib
```

But this only possible if you have access to this directory, which might not be the case for all ISPs. At least you can do it at home.

Bye

Comment: This makes the jar file available for all the web applications deployed in the server. The question mentions for a web application.

Comment: For the web application put it into WEB-INF/lib of your web application context. It will be automatically loaded by the context classloader.