# How to solve this java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/output/DeferredFileOutputStream?

Tags: servlets, upload, tomcat5.5

I am using the below code to upload a file in to tomcat5.5 and it gives me the following exception

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/output/DeferredFileOutputStream`

could you please help me to find it out?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class FileUploadServlet
 */
public class FileUploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public FileUploadServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
        System.out.println("Status : "+isMultipart);
        if (isMultipart) {
            FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

            try {
                List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
                Iterator iterator = items.iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    FileItem item = (FileItem) iterator.next();

                    if (!item.isFormField()) {
                        String fileName = item.getName();

                        String root = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
                        File path = new File(root + "/uploads");
                        if (!path.exists()) {
                            boolean status = path.mkdirs();
                        }

                        File uploadedFile = new File(path + "/" + fileName);
                        System.out.println(uploadedFile.getAbsolutePath());
                        item.write(uploadedFile);
                    }
                }
            } catch (FileUploadException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        response.sendRedirect("upload.jsp");
    }

}
```

this is the jar i use `commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The particular exception message is telling you that the mentioned class is missing in the classpath. As the `org.apache.commons.io` package name hints, the mentioned class is part of the [`http://commons.apache.org/io`](http://commons.apache.org/io) project.

And indeed, Commons FileUpload has Commons IO as a [dependency](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/dependencies.html). You need to [download](http://commons.apache.org/io/download_io.cgi) and drop `commons-io.jar` in the `/WEB-INF/lib` as well.

#### See also:

- [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/)
- [How to add JAR libraries to WAR project without facing java.lang.ClassNotFoundException? Classpath vs Build Path vs /WEB-INF/lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792197/how-to-add-jar-libraries-to-war-project-without-facing-java-lang-classnotfoundex)
- [How do I import the javax.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project)

Answer (score 19):

use maven dependency

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId> 
  <version>1.3.2</version> 
</dependency>
```

or download commons-io.1.3.2.jar to your lib folder

Comment: It's actually not contained in commons-io version 1.3.2.. try 2.4 or above. In the maven repo its not under 'org.apache' anymore but directly under 'commons-io:commons-io'

Answer (score 9):

Solution

By default, Struts is using Apache “commons-io.jar” for its file upload process. To fix it, you have to include this library into your project dependency library folder.

1. **Get Directly**

Get “commons-io.jar” from official website – http://commons.apache.org/io/

2. **Get From Maven**

The prefer way is get the “commons-io.jar” from Maven repository

File : pom.xml

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

just put all apache comons jar and file upload jar in lib folder of tomcat

Answer (score 1):

If you are receiving this error in a WebSphere container, then make sure you set your Apps class loading policy correctly. I had to change mine from the default to 'parent last' and also ‘Single class loader for application’ for the WAR policy. This is because in my case the commons-io*.jar was packaged with in the application, so it had to be loaded first.

Comment: Even if it doesn't answer the question it answered my question and google brought me here. So thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to download file from here https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi and select https://prnt.sc/tk5ewt

Now, Next add this downloaded files into your project:

Right click to your project ->Build path->Configure BuidPath -> https://prnt.sc/tk5d93