# getting error missing a runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, maven-3, spring-webflow

I am trying to setup Maven, JSF and Primefaces project. But when i run the project i get the following error

```
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
Source Document: jar:file:/D:/Personal%20Work/eclipse%2032%20Bit/workspace/Java%20EE
/Spring/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps
/ch18_SpringWebFlowAndJSF/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-3.5.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
Cause: Class 'org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUploadRenderer' is missing
 a runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload
/FileItem
```

Here is my POM snippet

```
<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.2.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
    <jsf-version>2.2.0</jsf-version>
</properties>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jsf-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${jsf-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>  
        <id>prime-repo</id>  
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>  
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>  
        <layout>default</layout>  
    </repository>     
</repositories>
```

Why i am getting this error?

Thanks

Comment: On which server you are deploying?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

java [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) says

> NoClassDefFoundError Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a
>   ClassLoader instance tries to load in the definition of a class (as
>   part of a normal method call or as part of creating a new instance
>   using the new expression) and no definition of the class could be
>   found.
>
> The searched-for class definition existed when the currently executing
>   class was compiled, but the definition can no longer be found.

**org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem** is a class in **FileUpload** component of Apache Commons which is missing in your class path. Add following maven dependency for **FileUpload** component in your pom.xml.

```
 <dependency>   
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>     
    <version>x.x</version>
 </dependency>
```

you can also check [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc)'s this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154252/how-to-solve-this-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-commons-io-output-d),

Comment: Hi i added a dependency `<dependency><groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId><artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId><version>1.3</version></dependency>` after that i am getting strange error `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.Collections.emptyIterator()Ljava/util/Iterator;`. Any idea what is that error ?

Comment: Commons collection is missing add commons collection jar

Comment: I had included this jar `commons-collection` but still i was getting the error. Then i remove the dependency `<dependency><groupId>commons-io</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-io</artifactId><version>20030203.000550</version></dependency>` and now things are ok :). Sure i will definitely accept your answer :) ;)

Comment: Why are you copying the words from an older answer of mine instead of writing in your own words and referencing the found duplicate question/answer as a link and if necessary in a blockquote? The downvote is not for the answer, but for the [plagiarism](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/ive-been-accused-of-plagiarism-what-do-i-do). Once you fix that, I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: thanks @BalusC I don't know about plagiarism. I have edited my answer can you remove your down vote.