# Glass fish 4 start failed in netbeans 7.3.1

Tags: jsf, netbeans, primefaces, glassfish-4

I've installed Netbeans 7.3.1 with GlassFish Server 4 but when I run web application(JSF-primcefaces + Hibernate) the default jsp(index.xhtml) page or any other pages I got the error:

```
DEFAULT=C:\Users\Ucf\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Agenda\build\web&name=Agenda&contextroot=/Agenda&force=true failed on GlassFish Server 4.0 
 Erreur lors du déploiement : Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
  Source Document: jar:file:/C:/Users/Ucf/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Agenda/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-3.5.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
  Cause: Class 'org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUploadRenderer' is missing a runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem. Pour plus d'informations, consultez le fichier server.log.
C:\Users\Ucf\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Agenda\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1040: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
```

Comment: You may check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089190/getting-error-missing-a-runtime-dependency-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org

Comment: The error is pretty straightforward: *Class `org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUploadRenderer` is missing a runtime dependency: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem`.* PrimeFaces 3.5 needs Apache Commons FileUpload jar and this jar isn't provided in your build path. Just add this library (download it/move it to WEB-INF/lib) or add the maven dependency in your pom.xml file (depending how you work with your project)