# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory

Tags: java, tomcat

I am using tomcat 7. Using eclipse Juno IDE.

I have added commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar file and commons-io-2.4.jar to the library folder using Build Path option.

Even after adding these library I am getting ClassNotFoundException.

Exception which I am getting

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/disk/DiskFileItemFactory
com.upload.uploadFileServlet.doPost(uploadFileServlet.java:53)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Comment: put the exception in OP

Comment: can you try putting in classpath?

Comment: i have added jar files using Build Path. Same thing I have done with servlet-api which was working but for commons file it is not working.

Comment: SpringLearner is right you have to put it in classpath

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154252/how-to-solve-this-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-commons-io-output-d

Comment: how it is differ from build path. And how to do it.