# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError cannot be cast to java.lang.Exception

Tags: java, excel, apache

I'm a problem with apache-poi, using:

- poi-3.7.jar
- poi-ooxml-3.7.jar

When I try to instace a new **workbook**:

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(someInputStream());
```

The application throw this **exception**:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError cannot be cast to java.lang.Exception
```

Complete stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError cannot be cast to java.lang.Exception
    at br.com.bradesco.web.aq.view.exceptionhandler.BradescoExceptionHandler.getOriginalException(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.bradesco.web.aq.view.exceptionhandler.BradescoExceptionHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at br.com.bradesco.web.aq.application.adapter.sso.sharedata.ShareDataFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at br.com.bradesco.web.aq.view.cryptography.filter.CryptoFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at br.com.bradesco.web.aq.view.filters.impl.AbstractBradescoFilterManager.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at br.com.bradesco.web.aq.application.session.filter.BradescoSessionFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at br.com.bradesco.web.aq.application.util.BeanResolverFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at br.com.bradesco.web.aq.view.components.UIFileUpload.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:238)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at br.com.bradesco.web.aq.view.filters.impl.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Thanks for some help.

Comment: This indicates serious classpath pollution. In Eclipse perspective, it looks like you placed POI libraries only in "build path" and that you placed JRE's libraries in /WEB-INF/lib. Both are Wrong. Are you aware of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6792197?

Comment: Thanks for comment, i will take a look

Comment: @BalusC, it's possible to generate xlsx with hssfworkbook?