# NoClassDefFoundError when using Tomcat 7 and trying to getConnection from OracleDataSource object

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, noclassdeffounderror, oracle12c

What I am wanting to do is open a connection to an Oracle Database 12c server using an `OracleTranslatingConnection` object so I can take advantage of the SQL Translation Framework that I have setup on a local 12c database.

The application I am working on uses Java 7 and Tomcat 7.

If I execute the snippet below outside of Tomcat, a connection is made, `simpleQuery` is properly translated, and I am given the correct results from the database.

However, if I execute the same snippet using Tomcat (excluding everything related to the Context) I receive the following exception once I reach the line `conn = ods.getConnection()`.

I have `ojdbc7.jar` and `asm-3.3.1.jar` (OJDBC needs ClassWriter?) in my classpath when I executed outside of Tomcat. When using Tomcat, the jars are in Tomcat's lib folder and they must be visible because I am able to instantiate those Oracle objects.

I started with [Oracle's API reference](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DRDAA/jdbc_api_ref.htm#DRDAA195) and ended up on Google with no success at finding a solution. The unhelpful solutions I have found so far involved a `ClassNotFoundException` with the necessary jars not in the right place, or reconfiguring Tomcat's server/web XML files (which I shouldn't need since I'm creating a data source myself, not looking it up through the Context), or connecting to the database in a way that is not using an `OracleDataSource`. I need that particular object so I can set the properties of the translation feature (see the line `props.put(...)`).

Would anyone be able to shed some light on what I'm missing here?

**Exception**

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/jdbc/internal/OracleConnection (wrong name: oracle/jdbc/proxy/oracle$1jdbc$1babelfish$1BabelfishConnection$2oracle$1jdbc$1internal$1OracleConnection$$$Proxy)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.jdbc.proxy.ClassGenerator$2.findClass(ClassGenerator.java:326)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.jdbc.proxy.ClassGenerator$2.findClass(ClassGenerator.java:326)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.jdbc.proxy.ClassGenerator.generate(ClassGenerator.java:319)
        at oracle.jdbc.proxy.ProxyFactory.prepareProxy(ProxyFactory.java:517)
        at oracle.jdbc.proxy.ProxyFactory.createProxy(ProxyFactory.java:479)
        at oracle.jdbc.proxy.ProxyFactory.proxyForCache(ProxyFactory.java:272)
        at oracle.jdbc.proxy.ProxyFactory.proxyFor(ProxyFactory.java:105)
        at oracle.jdbc.proxy.ProxyFactory.proxyFor(ProxyFactory.java:91)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.babelfishConnect(OracleDriver.java:657)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:561)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:317)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:241)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:184)
        at com.example.OracleTest.testOracle(OracleTest.java:60)
```

**Code Snippet**

```
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import java.util.Properties;
    import oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection;
    import oracle.jdbc.OracleTranslatingConnection;
    import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;

    public class OracleTest {

        private static String TRANSLATION_PROFILE_NAME = "SQLSERVER_PROFILE";

        private static void testOracle() throws SQLException {
            String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//server:1521/servicename";
            String jdbcUserName = "user";
            String jdbcPassword = "pass";
            Properties props = new Properties();
            OracleDataSource ods = null;
            OracleTranslatingConnection trConn = null;
            Statement trStmt = null;
            Connection conn = null;
            ResultSet trRs = null;
            String simpleQuery = "SELECT TOP 1 column1 FROM test_table ORDER BY column1 DESC";

            ods = new OracleDataSource();
            ods.setURL(jdbcUrl);
            ods.setUser(jdbcUserName);
            ods.setPassword(jdbcPassword);

            props.put(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_SQL_TRANSLATION_PROFILE, TRANSLATION_PROFILE_NAME);
            ods.setConnectionProperties(props);

            conn = ods.getConnection();

            trConn = (OracleTranslatingConnection) conn;
            trStmt = trConn.createStatement(true);
            trRs = trStmt.executeQuery(simpleQuery);

            while (trRs.next()) {
                System.out.println("column1: " + trRs.getString(1));
            }

            trRs.close();
            trStmt.close();
            conn.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possibly related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792197/when-and-where-to-add-jar-files-to-war-project-without-facing-java-lang-classnot)

Comment: @SameerPuri thanks for the suggestion, but I'm able to instantiate objects from the `ojdbc7.jar` so it is definitely in the right place and is being loaded so I do not believe that question is related.

Comment: Hmm, it's possible that it's related to a Tomcat security setting then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, after a back and forth with Oracle developer support, it was determined that this was a bug to be fixed in a version after 12.1, and I was unable to utilize the query translation feature.