# The import org.apache.commons.fileupload cannot be resolved

Tags: eclipse, jsp, file-upload, import, jar

I am trying to upload a file and store it on to server filesystem. I have imported following packages to my jsp file.

```
    <%@ page import = "org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.*" %>
    <%@ page import = "org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.*" %>
    <%@ page import = "org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.*" %>
```

But when importing, i am getting error "The import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk cannot be resolved". I have already imported necessary jar files to the classpath as well as /Web-Inf/lib.
[jar files imported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhYYb.png). Can someone help me?

The error should be resolved when i import necessary jar files right?

Edit: The link that has been shared talks talks about how to do the same via servlet. I want to do that using jsp.

Comment: You have the same import statement twice, and two versions of the same jar. Is your project using modules when you didn't intend to?

Comment: Please catch up the current state of technology. Already since 2009 you can simply use JSP/Servlet built-in file upload parsing functionality without the need to install 3rd party libraries/JARs. See abovelinked duplicate to get started.

Comment: In case you really really wish to ignore all modern tech and merely want to fix the currently observable problem in Eclipse-specific context, then head to this duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6792197

Comment: Hi @BalusC. I will definitely take a look into it. Thanks.

Comment: Just put the very same Java code in a JSP file instead of in a Java class then. Note that putting Java code in JSP files instead of Java classes is officially discouraged since JSP version 2.0 in 2003 because will in long term only end up in trouble.

Comment: Hi @BalusC, but we cannot use "@MultipartConfig" in jsp right? We can only use it in servlets.

Comment: You can use `<multipart-config>` in servlet mapping on the JSP file in web.xml. Or just use a normal Servlet. Much easier and natural and more safe to put Java code in a Java class instead of a JSP file. This way you also don't need any extra XML config.

Comment: Hi @BalusC thanks for input. However for the question "The import org.apache.commons.fileupload cannot be resolved", i have added necessary jars in /WEB-INF/lib path. Still the issue persists. Any inputs on that please? Thanks again.

Comment: /Web-INF/lib path is wrong. You need /WEB-INF/lib. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/6792774

Comment: I only wonder why you keep trying to go into the wrong direction as to implementing the concrete functional requirement. If this is home/schoolwork then you really need to reconsider another. Learning tech from previous century is absolutely not the way to go forward.

Comment: I have uploaded in /WEB-INF/lib. Thanks for the link @BalusC. I will have a look at it.

Comment: I understand @BalusC. I have a requirement where i have to use ONLY jsp to build an application. No Servlets. That's why i am sticking on to jsp path. Thank you.