# Error while converting image string to png file in java

Tags: java, png

I met with an error while doing a very simple task of converting image string to .png file.

`byte[] imgByteArray = Base64.decodeBase64(imageData.getBytes());`

Where imageData contains a long string which represents an image and there is nothing wrong in that string (I checked it by putting in a website that converts that to png).

But while executing that line it throws an error which says. filename: jasonreq.java

```
    Sep 01, 2014 12:37:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jasonreq threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1387)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
at com.example.fullscreensignature.jasonreq.doPost(jasonreq.java:45)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Kindly please tell me the reason behind this run time error. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` which is not on your classpath. You need to add the `.jar` (apache commons codec) that contains this file to your classpath.

See [Including external jar in Tomcat ClassPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163447/including-external-jar-in-tomcat-classpath) in your case.