# Tomcat - catalina.properties - giving jar that our in recursive folders/directories

Tags: tomcat8

I am trying to add dependencies in catalina.properties file under shared loader. I read article @ https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-classpath for basics.

I am writing for example -
shared.loader=C:\repository\FolderA\*.jar, C:\repository\FolderA\FolderB\*.jar, C:\repository\FolderC\*.jar

Since I want to include many jars, writing like this does not make sense.

How can tell tomcat to read all jars in directory or sub directory of C:\repository

Thanks

Comment: you might want to do it like described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163447/including-external-jar-in-tomcat-classpath. This has the clear advantage that you can use batch to iterate over all the jars and have them set in an environment variable instead of writing them by hand into the properties file